# Columns in Kendo Grid MVC Multiline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid MVC like this:

```
@(Html.NFSGrid<dynamic>("PortfolioGrid")
      .Name("PortfolioGrid")
      .EnableCustomBinding(true)
      //.Selectable()
      .BindTo(Model)
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(countpaging)
          .Model(m =>
          {

              foreach (var Allcoulms in (List<HtmlHelperGridBuilder.GridCol>)ViewData["ViewDataGridfildes"])
              {
                  if (Allcoulms.ColumnName == "Id")
                  {
                      m.Id(Allcoulms.ColumnName);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      m.Field(Allcoulms.ColumnName, Type.GetType("System.String")).Editable(true);
                  }

              }

          })

          .ServerOperation(true)

          .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Portfolio").Data("portFolioNameSpace.additionalInfo")
          )
      )
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:2000;" })
      .Columns(columns =>
      {


          columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate("<input name='selectedIds' type='checkbox' value=\"#=Id#\" class='check_row' onchange='portFolioNameSpace.changeChk(event,this.checked,this);'/>")
              .HeaderTemplate("<div  style='background=#C7CA21 ;width= 40%'><input type='checkbox' style='outline: 2px solid #cfbe62' class='selectAll' onclick='portFolioNameSpace.buttonclick(event)'/></div>")
              .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" })
              .Width(30);

          columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title(T("روند").ToString()).Width(30).ClientTemplate("<a onclick='portFolioNameSpace.onclickFlowFPortfolio(event)'><i class='iconmain-showall'></i></a>");
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title(T("اصل سند").ToString()).Width(50).ClientTemplate("<a onclick='portFolioNameSpace.GetFormData(event)'><i class='iconmain-Accepted'></i></a>");
          foreach (var Allcoulms in (List<HtmlHelperGridBuilder.GridCol>)ViewData["ViewDataGridfildes"])
          {
              if (Allcoulms.ColumnName == "Id")
              {
                  columns.Bound(Allcoulms.ColumnName).Visible(false);
              }
              else if (Allcoulms.ColumnName == "Subject")
              {
                  columns.Bound(Allcoulms.ColumnName).Width(Allcoulms.ColumnWidth).Title(T(Allcoulms.ColumnTitle).ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
              }
              else if (Allcoulms.ColumnName == "Comment")
              {
                  columns.Bound(Allcoulms.ColumnName).Width(200).Title(T(Allcoulms.ColumnTitle).ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).ClientTemplate("<input type=\"text\" id=\"#=Id#\" value=\"#=Comment#\"/>");
              }
              else if (Allcoulms.ColumnName == "notViewdRows")
              {

              }
              else
              {
                  columns.Bound(Allcoulms.ColumnName).Width(Allcoulms.ColumnWidth).Title(T(Allcoulms.ColumnTitle).ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
              }
          }



      })


              .Pageable(pager => pager.Enabled(true))
              .Scrollable()
              .Filterable()
               .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns((true)))
              .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))

              .Events(e => e
                          .DataBound("portFolioNameSpace.gridDataBound")
              )


)
```

so the problem is when the lengh of a coulmn is more than what i set in width it makes 2line like this picture so how can i make it 1ine without set specific width?
[image: My Screen Shot Of Grid For 2 Line Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the CSS attributes `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;` to the column definition, something like this:

```
columns.Bound(Allcoulms.ColumnName).Width(Allcoulms.ColumnWidth).Title(T(Allcoulms.ColumnTitle).ToString()).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" });
```

I tested and it works, see if it works for you too.

**EDIT**

Since you're using column templates, you also have the option of adding the CSS properties directly in your CSS file or even inline (although the latter isn't a good practice)